# ruby/rails array all elements between two indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array like this: `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

What's the simplest way to return each item in the array from position 6 until 0 where the resulting array looks like: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

This positions in the array can be dynamic, for example passing in 4 and 9 should return `[11,12,1,2,3,4]`

I'm wondering if there's a method that accomplishes this in Rails api.

Thanks in advance

EDIT
Let's assume that no negative numbers, so doing `array[2..-2]` wont work.

`Array#splice` almost works for this, but if the second position is less than the first, it returns `nil`.

Comment: What did you try for it?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

Comment: you can do a= [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and a[4..9] => [11,12,1,2,3,4]

Comment: What do you mean by "until 0"?

Comment: @sawa 0 being the first item in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Array
   def get_sub_array(start,last)
       (start > last) ? (self[start..-1] + self[0..last]) : self[start..last]
   end
end
```

Then

```
a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.get_sub_array(6,0)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Or if you don't want to monkey patch

You could have a method like

```
def get_sub_array(array, start,last)
   (start > last) ? (array[start..-1] + array[0..last]) : array[start..last]
end

a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
get_sub_array(a,6,0)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: If you are going to to monkey patch a core object at least get the naming right `Array#get_sub_array`. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Thank you. I am from C# background. Fast fingers made the mistake unknowingly :)

Comment: Ruby naming is actually dead simple compared to PHP, javascript etc - everything should be snake_case unless it's some form of constant like a Class / ModuleName or an actual CONSTANT.

Comment: why do you use `<<` and `flatten` instead of `array[start..-1] + array[0..last]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
def foo a, min, max
  a.rotate(min).first((max - min) % a.length + 1)
end

a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
foo(a, 6, 0) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
foo(a, 4, 9) # => [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I figured someone would have taken `rotate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_function(some_array,start_val=6, end_val=0)
  if end_val > start_val
    some_array[start_val,(end_val - start_val)]
  else
    (some_array[start_val, some_array.size] << some_array[0, (end_val)]).flatten
  end
end
```

You can use ternary operator to make it one liner too:

```
def some_function(some_array,start_val=6, end_val=0)
  end_val > start_val ? some_array[start_val,(end_val - start_val)] : (some_array[start_val, some_array.size] << some_array[0, (end_val)]).flatten
end

a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
some_function(a) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
some_function(a, 4, 9) # => [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min=6
max=0
arr = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result = []
if max<min
  result << arr[min..arr.length]
  result << arr[0..max]
else
  result << arr[min..max]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo a, s, e
  a = e < s ? (a[s,a.size] << a[0..e]).flatten : a[s..e]
end

a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a = foo(a, 6, 0) # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a = foo(a, 4, 9) # => [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple more ways (my preference being for #1).

```
a = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**#1**

```
def foo a, min, max
  as = a.size
  max += as if max < min
  (min..max).map { |i| a[i%as] }
end

foo(a, 6, 0) # => [ 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
foo(a, 4, 9) # => [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**#2**

```
def foo a, min, max
  max += a.size if max < min
  e = a.cycle
  min.times { e.next }
  (max-min+1).times.map { e.next }
end

foo(a, 6, 0) # => [ 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
foo(a, 4, 9) # => [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
myArray[6..-1] returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
myArray[4..9] returns [11,12,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: oh, he wants to go through the last item back to the first.  don't think it lets you do that.

Comment: if you really do know the positions then you could do myArraya[6..11].to_a << a[0] to get [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]